# C compilation error - error: incompatible types when initializing type 'char' using type Union

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am getting the above compilation error inside the checkResponse method whenever I compile this code.
Any pointers on a solution would be amazing!

ERRORS: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'char' using type 'Marks' {aka 'union MARKS'}

This is coming on the lines with -
Student s = {fname, lname, id, age, markType, mark};

```
typedef struct STUDENT {

    //creating members in structure
    char fname[50], lname[50];
    char id[10];
    int age;
    int markType;
    Marks mark;

}Student;

typedef union MARKS {

    int point;
    char scale;

}Marks;

void checkResponse(Node **plist, int response){
    if(response == 1){
        char fname[50], lname[50], id[10];
        int age, markType;

        printf("Please provide the first name, last name, id, age, mark type(1, 2): ");
        scanf(" %s %s %s %d %d", fname, lname, id, &age, &markType);
        if(markType == 1){
            int point;
            printf("Please provide percentage mark: ");
            scanf(" %d", &point);
            Marks mark = {.point = point};
            Student s = {fname, lname, id, age, markType, mark};
            Node *toBeInserted = new_node(s);
            insert_node(plist, toBeInserted);
        } else if(markType == 2){
            char grade;
            printf("Please provide grade: ");
            scanf(" %c", &grade);
            Marks mark = {.scale = grade};
            Student s = {fname, lname, id, age, markType, mark};
            Node *toBeInserted = new_node(s);
            insert_node(plist, toBeInserted);
        } else {
            while(markType != 1 || markType != 2){
                printf("Invalid mark type provided");
                scanf(" %d", &markType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what this issue is but I am expecting a student struct to be created using the union of marks.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Marks` and `Student`

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre]. With emphasis on the *minimal* part. The problem could probably be replicated with just a few lines.

Comment: @dbush

Here you go -

typedef struct STUDENT {

 //creating members in structure
 char fname[50], lname[50];
 char id[10];
 int age;
 int markType;
 Marks mark;

}Student;

typedef struct NODE {
 Student value;
 struct NODE *next;
} Node;

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to add relevant information. And don't forget to include the definition for `Mark`.

Comment: You're still not telling us the whole story. That code should give you *plenty* of errors ([as seen here](https://godbolt.org/z/fPe59xG7v)). Always copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question.

Comment: Before future questions, please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget the [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code `Student s = {fname, lname, id, age, markType, mark};` attempts to initialize the first member of `Student`, `char fname[50]`, with the array `fname`. However, C does not support initializing an array with an array, except for a string literal. Instead, the list `fname, lname, id, age, markType, mark` serves as a list of initializers for the elements of the `fname` array member.

In this, the array `fname` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element and then to a `char` (and the compiler should warn about that), and the resulting `char` value is used to initialize `s.fname[0]`. Similarly, `lname` is converted and used to initialize `s.fname[1]`, and `id`, `age`, and `markType` are used to initialize `s.fname[2]`, `s.fname[3]`, and `s.fname[4]`. Then the compiler gets to `mark`. It is unable to convert the `Marks` type to `char`, so it issues an error message.

You cannot initialize the arrays in `s` this way. Initialize the members you can initialize:

```
Student s = { .age = age, .markType = markType, .mark = mark };
```

and then copy the desired data into the arrays:

```
strcpy(s.fname, fname);
strcpy(s.lname, lname);
strcpy(s.id, id);
```